# Changing the product custom option renderer

Tags: custom-options

I have custom options that are added to certain products dynamically using the `catalog_controller_product_view` event and my own observer.

Related: [How to add dynamic Select Custom Options in Observer](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/52412/how-to-add-dynamic-select-custom-options-in-observer)

I'd like to now use an option renderer other than the default. Ideally, I'd like to set my own `type` field to the option when created so that it uses my own value, ie:

```
$optionModel = Mage::getModel('catalog/product_option')
    ...
    ->setType('my_option_type')
    ...
```

This, of course, requires my custom option type to have an associated Block, Model, etc. This also seems to require rewriting the `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option` class to include my custom option type.

Unfortunately, the Magento team didn't think these option renderers would have been useful as templates, as the markup is essentially all created in the `getValuesHtml()` method inside the option's associated block class (ie. `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Select`)

**How can I set my own renderer (preferably as a template, none of this sloppy `getValuesHtml()` stuff) to a custom option that is created dynamically on product view?**

Really, all I need to do is add some additional `data` attributes to each option value's `input` element.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even tho custom option renderers can be added via layout update by calling `addOptionRenderer` on `product.info.options` block, using custom types will never work without rewriting `getGroupByType` method inside `Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option` class.

You can trick Magento to show your custom type on product view page by doing something like this in `local.xml`

```
<catalog_product_view>
        <reference name="product.info.options.wrapper">
            <block type="foo_bar/options" name="product.info.options" as="product_options" template="catalog/product/view/options.phtml">
                <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>text</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_text</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/text.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>file</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_file</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/file.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>select</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_select</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/select.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>date</type><block>catalog/product_view_options_type_date</block><template>catalog/product/view/options/type/date.phtml</template></action>
                <action method="addOptionRenderer"><type>test</type><block>foo_bar/options_test</block><template>foo_bar/options/test.phtml</template></action>
            </block>
        </reference>
    </catalog_product_view>
```

Block class:

```
class Foo_Bar_Block_Options extends Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options
{
    public function getOptionHtml(Mage_Catalog_Model_Product_Option $option)
    {
        if ($option->getType() == 'test') {
            $renderer = $this->getOptionRender(
                $option->getType()
            );
        } else {
            $renderer = $this->getOptionRender(
                $this->getGroupOfOption($option->getType())
            );
        }

        if (is_null($renderer['renderer'])) {
            $renderer['renderer'] = $this->getLayout()->createBlock($renderer['block'])
                ->setTemplate($renderer['template']);
        }

        return $renderer['renderer']
            ->setProduct($this->getProduct())
            ->setOption($option)
            ->toHtml();
    }
}
```

And this will work until you try to add to cart because that is when `getGroupByType` is called again and we get a nice error message. :)

Comment: I guess I don't really care so much about what happens when adding to cart, since that is where I am already adding my options as `additional_options` after I perform necessary price calculations. It's fine that they use default renderers there, since that's pretty much what they are, I simply need to add some data values into the `<input>` that gets generated.

Comment: Is the renderer block (`Foo_Bar_Block_Options_Test` in your example) simply "there"? Should it use `getValuesHtml()`? Using  your example, this doesn't seem to be working.

Comment: Oh, I forgot to add it. It's just an empty class which extends `Mage_Catalog_Block_Product_View_Options_Type_Text`

Comment: Yeah, I figured that. I forgot I previously modified the options.phtml template to remove the call to `$option->getOptionHtml()` - This is pretty much exactly what I needed, thanks!